# Stack overflow when creating a new instance of a class

Tags: actionscript-3, stack-overflow

I am new to Action Script and very confused about why I am getting a stack overflow. I will post all 3 classes (what's relevant). And the output I get. Can someone explain to me why this will cause a stack overflow?

```
Main Class:

        public function Main() {
            //Problem starts here
            player1 = new Player();
            player2 = new Player();
// More code that does not matter
        }
```

Player Class:

```
package  {

    import fl.motion.Color;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Player extends MovieClip {

        public function Player() {
            var index:Finger = new Finger();
            var middle:Finger = new Finger();
            var ring:Finger = new Finger();
            var pinkie:Finger = new Finger();
        }
    }   
}
```

Finger Class:

```
package  {

    public class Finger extends Player {

        var colorOn:String;

        public function Finger(){
            colorOn = ""
        }

        function SetColor(colour:String):void {
            this.colorOn = colour;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Is this where stack overflow accuros?
Error: Error #1023: Stack overflow occurred.
    at flash.display::DisplayObject()
    at flash.display::InteractiveObject()
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer()
    at flash.display::Sprite()
    at flash.display::MovieClip()
    at Player()
    at Finger()
    at Player()
    at Finger()
    at Player()
    at Finger()
    at Player()
    at Finger()
    at Player()
    at Finger()
    at Player()
    at Finger()
    at Player()
    at Finger()
    at Player()
    at Finger()
    at Player()
    at Finger()
    at Player()
    at Finger()
    at Player()
    at Finger()
    at Player()
    at Finger()
    at Player()
    at Finger()
    at Player()
    at Finger()
    at Player()
    at Finger()
    at Player()
    at Finger()
    at Player()
    at Finger()
    at Player()
    at Finger()
    at Player()
    at Finger()
    at Player()
    at Finger()
    at Player()
    at Finger()
    at Player()
    at Finger()
    at Player()
    at Finger()
    at Player()
    at Finger()
    at Player()
    at Finger()
    at Player()
    at Finger()
    at Player()
    at Finger()
    at Player()
    at Finger()
    at Player()
    at Finger()
    at Player()
```

Comment: On your finger class constructor, didn't you miss a semicolumn ? Shouldn't it be like this: this.colorOn = "";

Comment: That would have shown as a compile time error. I fixed it but I have the same error though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to create a `Player`, you create four new `Finger` objects... but each `Finger` object is also a `Player` (because `Finger` extends `Player`). Therefore creating each of those four `Finger` objects requires creating four *more* `Fingers`, etc... hence the stack overflow.

That's *why* it's happening - unfortunately we don't have enough context of what you're trying to achieve to suggest the right fix, necessarily. The simplest approach may well be to stop `Finger` from extending `Player` - are you sure it should be doing so?